# String to bytes in both Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, string, binary, type-conversion

My function needs to take input as either a string or binary data (e.g., read from a file). If it's a string, I want to convert this to raw data (`bytes` or `bytearray`).

In Python 3, I can do `data = bytes(data, 'utf8')`. However, this fails in Python 2 as it only takes one argument. Vice versa, `data = bytes(data)` works in Python 2, but not in Python 3 as it complains about needing an encoding to work to.

For the sake of argument, let's say that all input, if it comes as a string, is UTF-8 encoded. Is there then a better way to achieve what I'm looking for than the following monstrosity:

```
try:
  data = bytes(data, 'utf8')
except:
  data = bytes(data)
```

n.b., `data.encode()` works in Py3, but fails in Py2 in the case that the string contains non-ASCII bytes.

Comment: Why do you need it to work in both?  You don't have separate versions for each?

Comment: It's library code and if I can have it be version agnostic, then all the better

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check the version using sys.version_info:

```
if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
    data = bytes(data)
else:
    data = bytes(data, 'utf8')
```

It is more pythonic than relying on exceptions.

Comment: This will also fail for older versions of python

Comment: @PadraicCunningham what is the minimum Python version this works for ?

Comment: As far as I know `>= 2.6`

Comment: The python community has adopted the EAFP (easier to ask forgiveness than permission) philosophy, so actually the try/except is more pythonic than this.

Comment: @cowlinator  You are correct if you can catch a specific exception. Catching a general exception is bad practice.

Comment: Ah, yes, good point.  I believe the exception in this case would be `TypeError`

Comment: Keep in mind this will fail in Python 2 if `data` has non-ascii characters.

Answer (score 11):

This works with both version. i.e. python 2 and python 3

```
data = bytes(str(data).encode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're using the six py2/3 compatibility library, you may prefer:

```
import six
data = bytes(data) if six.PY2 else bytes(data, 'utf8')
```